# Stack view constraints changes top-layer's view width

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, xcode9.2

I have a stack view holding 2 images.

[image: No stack view leading constraint]

1. One image's width to be lower or equal to 140 and 1:1 ratio
2. Stack view top constraint 20 and trailing constraint 5

When I want to set the stack view leading constraint to 5 (looking at the safe area leading) it enlarges the safe area to a width of 1920 and I have no idea why it does that.

[image: stack view leading constraint (fill equally)]

It might have something to do with that the total width of the stack view (including the constraints) is smaller than the width of the safe area so it's ignoring the images width constraint and enlarging it to the default size (1920)? Because, when I change the stack view's distribution to fill proportionally instead of fill equally it does obey to the image's width constraint and the safe view's width stays normal.

[image: fill proportionally]

If I am thinking correctly, how can I find a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I was trying to think logically and I found a solution by changing the image's width to GREATER or equal to instead of SMALLER or equal to. I was following a devslopes guide and in that Xcode version (Beta XCode9) it did work, it just gave a warning it wasn't obeying that constraint anymore (I think it was saying that, I just saw the width being red). So it works now, if anyone has this problem following their guide, just do what I said and it will work.